# Ruby Devise 2.2 add email address along with the user.email

Tags: ruby, devise

Currently I am using `ruby devise gem 2.2.3`. And I tried to customize the **confirmation_instructions** for adding couple of email ids with the user email.

app/mailers/my_devise_mailer.rb

```
class MyDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer  
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

  def confirmation_instructions(record, opts={})   
    opts[:to] = "example1@mail.com, example2@mail.com"    
    super 
  end
end
```

config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.mailer = "MyDeviseMailer"
```

And, I ran the following in my console

```
user = User.first
MyDeviseMailer.delay.confirmation_instructions(user)
```

I got a output without body message. PFA

**Correct**
[image]

**Wrong**
[image]

Can anyone tell me what I missed to add/configure?

Comment: Can you post the template that this mailer uses? It should be in `app/views/devise/mailer`

Comment: YEs, it's there named as confirmation_instructions.html.haml

Comment: And it contains the proper body?

Comment: Yes of-course. That's why first one is showing the correct body content.

Comment: Updated my answer. This is the simpler & cleaner solution I could find.

Comment: Yes, I thought it's a very correct and sweat answer until I am facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new mailer instead and modify the headers of that one:

```
# app/mailers/my_mailer.rb
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer
  def headers_for(action, opts)
    if action == :confirmation_instructions    
      super.merge!(to: ['example1@mail.com', 'example2@mail.com'])
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Then tell Devise to use your mailer:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.mailer = MyMailer
```

Comment: Thanks Agis. I tried. Everything is working fine but still, I can't see the body content.

Comment: And if you undo this change and try again, you see the body content just fine?

Comment: :) then, it'll break requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`super.merge!"` will not work. Because it'll replace the value for the given key (:to). But, the requirement is to add two mail id's with 'To'. The following gist is working fine.

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer  
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

  def headers_for(action, opts={})
    begin
      super.merge!(to: [super[:to], 'example1@mail.com', 'example2@mail.com'], template_path: ["devise/mailer"]) if action == :confirmation_instructions
    rescue Exception => e
      super         
    end
  end

end
```

Happy Coding!!